# Know of any other wordplay analogies?

Tags: word, wordplay

I found these "wordplay analogies" in my [Mensa 365 Brain Puzzlers Page-A-Day Calendar 2016](https://smile.amazon.com/Mensa-Brain-Puzzlers-Page-Calendar/dp/0761183663):

```
1. TRIGLYPHS is to SPLIT as PROBOSCIS is to _________
2. CUP is to COUPLE as NAYS is to _________
3. HALVE is to ALIVE as THOSE is to _________
4. DOWNFALL is to UPRISE as OVERCOME is to _________
```

I thoroughly enjoyed these (and I hope you do, too!) However, they left me craving more.

Does anyone know of other examples or sources of these kinds of wordplay analogies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. SCOOP (reverse, and take alternate letters)
>
>  3. HOUSE (increment first letter, remove it and insert it as 3rd letter)
>
>  4. UNDERGO (element-level analogy using opposites)

Comment: I would say naples, for number two: adding the pull sound after 3 letters

Comment: I think it's more likely to be 'nasal'

Comment: @PatrickN, that's better than the "nacelle" that I was thinking.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the Miller Analogies Test (MAT) is an alternative to the GRE, and it's just 120 analogies, but most of these involve domain knowledge or vocabulary rather than wordplay.

Also, the only free practice tests are ones like [this one](http://www.majortests.com/mat/miller-analogy-test01), which aren't official, and which include some illogical answers (e.g. PITCH is to LOUDNESS as WAVELENGTH is to AMPLITUDE - it makes much more sense to have PITCH with WAVELENGTH and LOUDNESS with AMPLITUDE.)

Comment: seems logical, when traveling departure comes first.

Comment: Hm you're right, I was thinking that arrival (e.g. at a party) comes before departure, but your interpretation makes more sense. I've changed my answer to instead address another pattern I found odd.