# More wordplay analogies

Tags: word, wordplay

Here are some more "wordplay analogies" from my [Mensa 365 Brain Puzzlers Page-A-Day Calendar 2016](https://smile.amazon.com/Mensa-Brain-Puzzlers-Page-Calendar/dp/0761183663) (first post [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/38030/know-of-any-other-wordplay-analogies/38031)):

```
1. MUFFINS is to SNIFF as PATRONS is to __________
2. THINE is to FATE as USE is to __________
3. CABARET is to BERET as BALLERINA is to __________
4. LIVED is to MOCHA as VIVID is to __________
```

Does anyone know of other examples or sources of these kinds of wordplay analogies?

Comment: The question is to find out other such examples or to fill in the blanks?

Comment: Interesting - I got that calendar for Christmas and I've been doing them one-a-day all year. I did these this morning and just got surprised to see them appear on here too xD

Comment: @Sid The puzzle is to fill in the blanks. My follow-up question (not a puzzle) is if anyone knows of other examples of these, since I really enjoy this kind of puzzles.

Comment: @Joe Hah! These are the only puzzles I've posted from the calendar, since I'm hoping to find similar ones. I've also got a stack of ~30 half-completed puzzles that I can't quite get.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. > SNORT - Reverse and drop last two letters.
2. > THEME - Ignore last letter, reverse meaning (THIN-> FAT, US->THEM)
3. > ARENA - Drop the first syllable but pronounce the remaining syllables the same.
4. > From @BeastlyGerbil: COCOA - using subsitutions V = C, I = O, D = A

Comment: Argh, for #3 I was stuck on "Lerina".  At least the dictionary agrees with my syllabification.

Comment: @Hellion Yes, that was the one that I was unsure about, too, for the same reason.

Answer (score 5):

**1.**

> SNORT - it's the last 5 letters backwards

**2.**

> (From @fortyCakes) THEME - drop last letter and change meaning

**3.**

> ARENA - Take the last 5 letters and then pronounce the same

**4.**

> COCOA - V = C, I = O, D = A